# Can't install linux headers for ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, linux-headers

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-4.10.0-42-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-headers-4.10.0-42-generic' has no installation candidate
```

I suspect that this might be the problem behind the failed installation of new nvidia drivers.

Any ideas how to solve?

Some maybe helpful info:

uname -r

```
4.10.0-42-generic
```

dpkg-query -s linux-headers-$(uname -r)

```
dpkg-query: package 'linux-headers-4.10.0-42-generic' is not installed and no information is available
```

sudo apt list --installed | grep headers

```
libxmu-headers/artful,artful,now 2:1.1.2-2 all [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-4.13.0-41/artful-updates,artful-updates,artful-security,artful-security,now 4.13.0-41.46 all [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-4.13.0-41-generic/artful-updates,artful-security,now 4.13.0-41.46 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-4.13.0-43/artful-updates,artful-updates,artful-security,artful-security,now 4.13.0-43.48 all [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-4.13.0-43-generic/artful-updates,artful-security,now 4.13.0-43.48 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-headers-generic/artful-updates,artful-security,now 4.13.0.43.46 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: Considering that 17.10 uses kernel version 4.13.x, it's not surprising that 4.10.x (much older) is not in the 17.10 repositories.

Comment: @user535733 so the question here is rather why I get 4.10.x to uname -r ?

Comment: You tell us. Why are you running a 17.04 kernel on a 17.10 system? Does your system not upgrade kernels? Are there errors? Did you disable something? Have you hardwired GRUB into a specific configuration? What happens when you try to upgrade kernels (instead of headers)? Did you simply forget to reboot in the last 12 months?

Comment: @user535733 thanks for catching that, I guess that is the next issue to focus to. I do not know why/how this happened, the grub config seems normal (as far as I can compare it with others). If you  post this as an answer (e.g. "the problem relies on your uname -r pointing to 17.04 kernel headers") I will accept it.

Comment: It's not an answer to your problem. It's but one stepping stone along the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Could not find linux-headers- ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine
```

I issued these commands after reading many approach to this error after : `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-server`

1. `uname -r`
2. `sudo apt-get list | grep headers`
3. `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`

The command gave me generic that was installed, the `uname` and the right `linux-headers` was installed. Gurls it works!